# Is it time to unlock/vote to reopen old book recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion, resource-recommendation

Looking at old book recommendation questions, I noticed that some of them were closed or locked almost a decade ago. But our policy on book recommendations today is much more liberal. Is it time to unlock / reopen the following questions?

- [Graduate Physics Problems Books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10325/)
- [Best physics olympiad resources](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22696/)
- [List of freely available physics books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6157/)
- [Best Sets of Physics Lecture Notes and Articles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101187/)
- [What is a good introductory text to astronomy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25512/)

Some of these are certainly very general, but others are definitely specific enough that they wouldn't be closed today.

Comment: I don't know if they should be reopened, but at a minimum I would think all of the answers would need to be revised to make it conform with the policy. Not saying that's sufficient to reopen, but it would certainly be a necessary condition. Normally we don't require answers to justify the question, but book recommendations have a weird set of rules and only exist because the community agreed to curate the answers properly.